# How is the anniversary of Vostok 1 celebrated in the U.S. space community?

Tags: history, united-states, vostok-program

Sixty years ago, the first human spaceflight was celebrated in the Soviet Union as a great technical and historic victory.  Americans at the time were concerned that the United States was losing the space race.

Attitudes in the United States are different today.  Russia and the U.S. cooperate together with the International Space Station.  **How is Gagarin's first spaceflight celebrated today by the American space community?**

---

*This is the last of [6 questions honoring the 60th anniversary of Vostok 1, the first human spaceflight](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1746/26446).*

Comment: What do you mean by celebrated?  Various U.S. Government officials send congratulatory tweets each year.  And of course there are Yuri's Night parties all over the world, including many in the States (normally, not during covid so much)

Comment: @SpaceLawyer: Either of these would be sufficient as an answer.

Comment: Yuri's Night was celebrated at the Outpost Tavern. The Outpost is gone. It caught on fire, and then Egret Bay Blvd was expanded. There are (or were, pre-COVID) Yuri's Runs during the day in the Houston area. It has become commercialized.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Would you mind writing an answer?